# Load 32-bit Zint.dll in Delphi 64-Bit Program

Tags: delphi, dll, 32bit-64bit

I'm using Zint.dll to show a QR Code in a Delphi program.
When I compile to 32 bit it loads the QR Code properly but when I compile to 64 bit it does not load, as the DLL is 32.

Is there any way to convert a DLL to a 64-bit version so it should be working on with my program?

Comment: Just in case you find such a converter: please tell so, since I also have a few 16 bit executables I'd like to patch to 32 or 64 bit. Not to mention 64 bit executables I'd like to have in 16 bit for FreeDOS. See also [Convert a 32 bit windows driver to 64 bit. Is it possible?](https://superuser.com/a/415295/650342) from 11 years ago.

Comment: There is a Zint Delphi source code repo on GitHub so you don't need a DLL anymore! https://github.com/landrix/Zint-Barcode-Generator-for-Delphi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just convert an existing 32bit executable into a 64bit executable. Its source code needs to be **recompiled** into a native 64bit executable.

If you can't recompile the DLL yourself, and can't obtain a precompiled 64bit version of the DLL from somewhere else, then you will just have to load the existing 32bit DLL into a separate 32bit process that uses IPC (interprocess communication) techniques (sockets, pipes, RPC, etc) to communicate and exchange data back and forth between your 32bit and 64bit processes as needed.

Comment: Thanks, but the Zint.Dll is not something I have access to.
It is a compiled DLL, I want to use it in My Delphi 64-Bit Program...

Comment: @codeGood  I figured as much, which is why I suggested the surrogate approach. You CANNOT use a 32bit DLL in a 64bit process, only in a 32bit process, period. So, your 64bit process will need a separate 32bit helper process to access the DLL, receiving data from the 64bit process to pass into the DLL, and sending data from the DLL back to the 64bit process, as needed.

Comment: Thanks. I never used the surrogate approach. Any advice or link to how to do it in Delphi?

Comment: There is no single approach to implementing this. You have to come up with your own protocol between the 32bit and 64bit processes, as appropriate for your code. I mentioned several possible ways in my answer. There are other ways, too.

Comment: Apparently, the original author of Zint.Dll is not interested in making a 64bit version, but you could always download its source code (it is on [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/p/zint/)) and recompile it as 64bit yourself.

Comment: Can I trust SourceForge?

Comment: Really, only you can decide that for yourself. But SourceForge used to be THE place to go for open-source software, before CodePlex and GitHub came along. But there are still some good quality projects on SourceForge.

Comment: *Can I trust SourceForge?* You already are - you're using a DLL that was compiled from that source code.